# Cannot send command output into an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to place each `sysctl -a` output line into an array:

```
TAB=($(sysctl -a))
```

It does not work; the resulting array contains the output split on any whitespace, instead of only on newlines:

```
[..]
NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.5
=
NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.6
=
NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.7
=
NONE
net.netfilter.nf_log.8
[..]
```

I try:

```
while read -r line
   do
      TAB+=("${line}") 
   done< <(sysctl -a)
```

That does not work neither (same issue).

I try:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line 
   do
      TAB+=("${line}") 
   done< <(sysctl -a)
```

But still same output, same issue.

What's the correct method to have each line correctly placed in the array?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream

Comment: @LéaGris, the accepted solution on that question will split the command output on _whitespace_ which is the problem achille is having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way - probably the easiest - is to use `readarray` (bash 4 needed).

```
readarray -t TAB < <(sysctl -a)
```

Test:

```
$ echo ${TAB[0]}
abi.vsyscall32 = 1

$ echo ${TAB[1]}
crypto.fips_enabled = 0
```

Comment: Without Bash4 you just use `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a TAB < <(sysctl -a)`

Comment: .@cornuz: Nice tip! I can make my way with this. I am just wondering if there is a way to fecth each element from the array without specifying an index - echo ${TAB[index]} -, so that I can get rid of a counter in my snippet.

Comment: @achille You probably mean `for x in "${TAB[@]}"; do echo ${x}; done`, like in user1934428's answer? Although, what's the point of having an array then?

Comment: .@cornuz : for loop does not work here (you get back to the issue I described). you need to echo ${TAB[index]}; I found my way: I make an infinite loop, as soon as [ -n ${TAB[index]} ] is false, I break the loop. This way, I dont mind about how many lines the output contains. thanx again.

Comment: @achille `for x in "${TAB[@]}"; do` should iterate over the array's elements properly -- did you include the double-quotes? Skipping them will cause something like the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
IFS=$'\n' TAB=($(sysctl -a)) 
# Usage example:
for x in "${TAB[@]}"
do
  echo $x
done
```